# Difference between writing #import <filename.h> and #import "filename.h" i.e written the file name in angular brackets and quotes?

Tags: xcode, xcode3.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is the difference between #include <filename> and #include “filename”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)

Difference between writing #import   and #import "filename.h" i.e written the file name in angular brackets and quotes?

Answer (score 2):

Quoted form This form instructs the preprocessor to look for include files in the same directory of the file that contains the #include statement, and then in the directories of any files that include (#include) that file. The preprocessor then searches along the path specified by the /I compiler option, then along paths specified by the INCLUDE environment variable.

Angle-bracket form  This form instructs the preprocessor to search for include files first along the path specified by the /I compiler option, then, when compiling from the command line, along the path specified by the INCLUDE environment variable.

Source http://msdn.microsoft.com

Comment: This question is about Xcode, so I don't quite understand why you're referring to MSDN...

Comment: @Glenn85, the same thing applies to Xcode