# What is the difference between #import "xxx" and #import <xxx>?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between #include <filename> and #include “filename”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21593/what-is-the-difference-between-include-filename-and-include-filename)
>   [Difference between writing #import <filename.h> and #import “filename.h” i.e written the file name in angular brackets and quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156432/difference-between-writing-import-filename-h-and-import-filename-h-i-e-wri)

This might be a stupid question. What is the difference between `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` and `#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"`? (*greater-than/less-than vs the double-quotes*)

They both seem to work.

Comment: repeat of this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156432/difference-between-writing-import-filename-h-and-import-filename-h-i-e-wri

Comment: Ah, was having trouble finding those questions. Please close as duplicate.

Comment: That's duplicate. Follow this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3162030/difference-between-angle-bracket-and-double-quotes-while-including-heade

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general the `#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"` form is "find my very own header, if you can't find it look for a system header", and the `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` form is "find a system header".    In theory the locations are compiler defined and they could be implemented differently on a given platform, but I haven't run into a C compiler that does anything different.

Comment: the `#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"` doesn't look for a system header. its xCode that imports frameworks to local headers.

Comment: The double quote version looks for system headers if local ones are not found, that is why he said "They both seem to work".   (there is a build setting to make <> search user paths first, but I didn't figure it was all that important for this question) -- try #include "stdio.h" it'll find it.

Answer (score -2):

`#include <something>` tells the compiler to look in all include directories.
`#include "something"` tells the compiler to look only in the directory of the file with the include in it.

Comment: Not correct.  The standard explicitly states that if the normal search for `#include "something"` fails, it is reprocessed as though it said `#include <something>`.  So it is more correct to say that the quoted version looks in the same directory *first*, but then looks in all the include directories.