# AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h file not found

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avfoundation, file-not-found

When I create an iOS project,and "Build Phases -> Link binary with Libraries", I add the AVFoundation.framework lib and use `#import "<AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>"`. I get a compilation error:

> "AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h  file not found".

Here's my code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "<AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>"
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

There is only two types of `#import` statements:

```
#import <file.h>
```

and

```
#import "file.h"
```

There is no type like : `#import "<file.h>"` you are making mistake here:  `#import "<AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>"`

> In general the #import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h" form is "find my very
>   own header, if you can't find it look for a system header", and the
>    form is "find a system header". In theory
>   the locations are compiler defined and they could be implemented
>   differently on a given platform, but I haven't run into a C compiler
>   that does anything different.

Reference: [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8424188/what-is-the-difference-between-import-xxx-and-import-xxx)

Answer (score 9):

You have extra quotes.

Use

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

not

```
#import "<AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>"
```

Comment: thanks for your answer very much. you correct me. but  Midhun MP is a little faster than you, thanks you all the same

Answer (score 1):

please do not use

```
#import "<AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>"
```

use this

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
```

we can import two type of library

first one is System Library which are developed by Apple developer

are imported as

```
 #import <Library.h>
```

Second one is Classes implemented by Application developer

like as

```
#import "Library.h"
```