# Preferred method of importing for a source file from a Third Party?

Tags: ios, objective-c, import, frameworks, cocoapods

Which is the preferred method of importing for a source file from a Third Party?

I have the third party library (YLTableView) installed via CocoaPods.

**e.g.**

```
#import "YLTableViewDataSource.h"
```

*or*

```
#import <YLTableView/YLTableViewDataSourceSubclass.h>
```

Please provide reasoning as to why one is preferrable over the other.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a framework that you are importing then you use:

`#import <frameworkName/FrameworkGlobalHeader.h>`

If it is not a library then just use:

`#import "headerfile.h"`

Comment: Thanks - as per question "Please provide reasoning as to why one is preferrable over the other."

Comment: @Ríomhaire, Hope this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156432/difference-between-writing-import-filename-h-and-import-filename-h-i-e-wri